# Django - Filterset without model

Tags: django, django-filter

I have such http-request route:

```
frontend > proxy (drf) service > data service (sap)
```

The view in `proxy service`:

```
def get_data_from_remote_api():
    # this is mock

    return [
        {'first_name': 'Brad', 'last_name': 'Pitt'},
        {'first_name': 'Thomas', 'last_name': 'Cruise'},
        {'first_name': 'Robert', 'last_name': 'Downey'},
    ]


class RemoteUsersView(ViewSet):
    # TODO: 
    #    define filtering class (data from query params) 
    #    with multiple fields (`first_name`, `last_name`) 
    #    so it is displayed in swagger

    def list(self, request):
        users = get_data_from_remote_api()
        # here need to filter
        return Response('list')

    def create(self, request):
        return Response('create')

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        return Response('retrieve')

    def update(self, request, pk):
        return Response('update')

    def destroy(self, request, pk):
        return Response('destroy')
```

As you can see a list of dicts should be filtered. So I cannot use FilterSet because it needs Django model.

How can I define a filter class?

Comment: Take a look at the source of Django-filters for how to deal with the request.GET parameters. Obviously if your data is in memory you can't be using a Django Queryset on it, so you'll have to create and implement filters some other way.